# How do you make a function for a n-pointed star? in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Im trying to make a function named star for an n-pointed star with radius 1, center (0,0) and start line is (0,1) with an angle n(((n-1)/n)*Pi). How??

My end goal is to make the star on the image I posted:

[image: 1]

What mathematica functions do I use? graphics, Line, Table??

If possible id love an example :D.

I have not gotten far, the only code I have written is: star[n_] := Graphics[Table[Line[{}, {}], {}]];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
star[n_]:=Graphics[Line[Table[{Cos[t*(n-1)^2/n*Pi],Sin[t*(n-1)^2/n*Pi]},{t,0,n}]]];
star[5]
star[13]
```

Take it apart, look at what just the `Table[...]` gives you. And exactly why does that use `{t,0,n}` instead of `{t,0,n-1}`. And why does it have `(n-1)^2/n` in it, what does that do? Then look up the documentation for `Line[...]` and see what it accepts for input and how the output of `Table[...]` provides that.

Then the challenging part is that you have to reverse engineer my thought process to figure out what I was thinking and how I got to `t*(n-1)^2/n*Pi`. If you believe you understand all this then see if you can rewrite the calculations in a different way and still get the same result. And then can you find a way to make this much simpler and easier to understand exactly what it is doing and exactly why?